# AutoCad script: running a few objects in a row

Tags: autocad

I'm really new to AutoCad and I'm trying to write a first script. I have problem with it, though. 
I want to have a few objects in my picture and I'm trying to call them one after another but they seem to work only separately. When I run the whole script, just two objects are drawn, no more. What is missing between the lines? I'd be grateful for your help!

This is my script:

```
_pline 297.3806,3728.9307
@3744.8216,0
@0,-3178.5797
@-3744.8216,0
@0,3178.5797

_ellipse 2847.31,2621.88 2647.16,2403.75 120.6928

_ellipse 2010.64,2594.83 1922.96,2478.61 109.6986

_circle 2350.2332,2121.3065 891.402
```

Answer (score 0):

New lines and spaces are important in scripts. 
In AutoCAD [ENTER] default means "repeat the last command".
so it's enougth to remove empty lines from Your code:

```
_pline 297.3806,3728.9307
@3744.8216,0
@0,-3178.5797
@-3744.8216,0
@0,3178.5797

_ellipse 2847.31,2621.88 2647.16,2403.75 120.6928
_ellipse 2010.64,2594.83 1922.96,2478.61 109.6986
_circle 2350.2332,2121.3065 891.402
```